# Can't find standalone Chrome Gmail client that I know exists

Tags: windows, google-chrome, gmail

I'm on Windows.

A couple years ago when I switched from Outlook to Gmail (Google Apps), Google provided this awesome little standalone gmail client that was just a single-purpose Chrome install. It launched like a normal application, stayed updated when I updated Chrome. It was Chrome in a separate application that launched only gmail, stayed logged in really well, and "felt" like a gmail mail client, with the gmail interface. It had it's own little red envelope icon, it was a windows app. (I remember there was no Mac equivalent.)

I found it while looking through the "this is how you get your company to switch to gmail" documentation that Google provided.

I just repaved my box and now I'm looking for this thing again, and I had no idea it would be impossible to find. I've spent literally 2 hours looking, searching, googling, etc. I'm losing my mind.

Anyone know how I can get my hands on this? I used it all day every day for 2 years, so I know it exists :), but I can not find it. Any assistance would be gratefully received.

Comment: Google for a site specific browser (SSB). This will allow you to set up your own!

Comment: Do you mean the application shortcuts in Chrome? There are essentially a shortcut to a window which will only show Chrome. They also do their own icons in the Start bar. You can make one by going to Gmail in Chrome. Then Click the wrench->tools->Create Application Shortcut.

Comment: slhck if I come up dry on this, I will - thanks. That's close. I really would like the one Google provided though.

Dracs, no, that's not it, but that too might be a passable alternative if my search ultimately fails. 

I'm honestly surprised how hard this is to find, I had no idea it was such a "hidden" tool.

Comment: @Dracs, I stand corrected - that essentially is exactly what I wanted, I had just come about it a much different way. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Dracs - I think your comment is the answer, but the suggested answers on this question are incorrect. Perhaps you would post as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

You can use an application shortcut in Chrome. This essentially tells Chrome to create a shortcut which will launch a browser window which will show the requested webpage. It will only show the window, no address bar, bookmarks, etc. They also have their own icon in the start bar, so they appear as a separate application.

To make an application shortcut, go to the website you want (in this case Gmail). Then click on the wrench (options menu)->Tools->Create Application Shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to http://dl.google.com/tag/s/ap=yourdomain.com/googlewebapps/en/googleappsstandalonesetuptagged.exe to download the tools.

If you're a Google Apps for Business user, you should replace `example.com` in the above URL with your domain name.

This will download the Google Apps installer which will create 3 new stand-alone applications:

- Google Calendar
- Google Docs
- Google Mail

These applications behave exactly as you described in your question.

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question. Clicking a random link to an executable  is not accepted by many users

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot [like gmail notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html) , Its currently EOLed (Not updated since 06) but it runs a small standalone system tray entry that tells you if you got mail, and lets you check mail senders, titles and snippets of the e mail.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [GmDesk](http://robertnyman.com/gmdesk/) considering how it is described...

> Run GMail, Google Calendar, Google Docs, Google Maps, Google Reader and Picasa Web Albums as a stand-alone application

Answer (score 0):

It's a link in the cpanel of your google apps domain.  Look for "advanced tools" then scroll down to "Google Apps desktop features".  There should be a download link there.